# Android app not appearing in Market for 1.5&1.6 devices, Bluetooth is android:required="false"

Tags: android-manifest, google-play, android-market-filtering

Our Android app can now use Bluetooth if available, but it is *not* required.
So I added these lines to the manifest:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:required="false"/>
```

**PROBLEM**: After publication, most people can download the app, but the app does not show up in the Market for:

- Android 1.5 HTC Magic
- Android 1.6 G1

What should I change so that it appears in the Market with those devices too?

Please note that we allow SDK level 3, which includes Android 1.5:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="11"/>
```

The previous version of the app did not have any Bluetooth support, and it was showing in everybody's Market.
An idea was that Android 1.5/1.6 does not understand `android:required="false"`, which would eliminate devices with no Bluetooth, but this hypothesis is invalidated by the fact that the previously mentioned G1 *has* Bluetooth.

*Details if needed: [full manifest](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/blob/v0.7/AndroidManifest.xml), [manifest of previous version](https://github.com/nicolas-raoul/Anki-Android/blob/v0.6/AndroidManifest.xml), [Market](https://market.android.com/details?id=com.ichi2.anki), [our internal discussion](http://code.google.com/p/ankidroid/issues/detail?id=744).*

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Maybe it's just impossible, because of security concerns: http://www.medieval.it/google-is-censoring-bluetooth-on-android-the-proof/menu-id-66.html

My solution would be to release a second version for 1.5/1.6 without these lines in the manifest for the market:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" android:required="false"/>
```

In the future, you could also inform them about an update and the download location (of the one and only bluetooth-build) from within ankidroid.

Another solution could be:

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-feature android:name="android.hardware.bluetooth" android:required="false" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" android:targetSdkVersion="11" />
...
</manifest>
```

or just:

```
<manifest ...>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.BLUETOOTH_ADMIN" />
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="3" />
...
</manifest>
```

Thanks for you generosity!

Source for that is: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-feature-element.html#bt-permission-handling

Comment: +1 Great link, exactly our problem! That's frightening :-( Is there an official notice written by Google about this? I hope we won't have to generate 2 applications, that would be a big pain for both us and our users.

Comment: Sounds unlikely, but maybe there is a way to not require Bluetooth for 1.5 and 1.6, without making 2 different apps?